# How to encrypt a short string into another SHORT string using OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption

I wish to take a string like "abcd-efgh" and perform an asymmetric encryption so that the resulting string is itself fairly short when export as hex - 20 characters or so.

I realise, of course, that this won't be very secure. It's not an issue for the use case in question.

The encrypted string needs to be generated in PHP and decrypted on a desktop application, so using OpenSSL would be useful.

I've tried using openssl_private_encrypt with a 2048 bit RSA key but the result is very long.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can look-up `textbook RSA`, it's without padding and deterministic. Try setting some PHP equivalent of C `EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding` to `RSA_NO_PADDING`.

Comment: Well, you could use a shorter key (80 bit) without any padding, but that doesn't doesn't have any security at all. Some libraries prevent you from creating keys shorter than 512 or even 1024 bit. I don't know if openssl would support this. Also, `openssl_private_encrypt` shouldn't be used for encryption if you expect the public key to be *public*.

Comment: Instead of asking about what you've assumed to be the best solution, explain the real problem and ask what the best solution would be.

Comment: @erickson I share tarmes' question. I bet it's something like a toy application / academic / just-for-fun. It's very cool to be able to have sub-512-byte strings that are self-contained encrypted; you can do this _symmetrically_, but I really want to see how it works _asymmetrically_.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Elliptic Curve](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography). It's still not small, but it's a lot more dense than RSA. 160 bits is non-trivial to break.